# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isAuthenticated') at Function.mapStateToProps

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Error says that it reads isAuthenticated as undefined, even though in my global state I have the variable under state.authReducer.isAuthenticated.

I'm using redux and it appears that I can't access the global state (I think the issue lies in store.js but I really don't know what exactly is the issue). Some fellow learner has posted a similiar (maybe identical) issue, but the answers did not help me as it still reads isAuthenticated as undefined.

**store.js**:

```
const initialState = {};
const middleware = [thunk];
const store = legacy_createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
);

export default store;
```

**authReducer**:

```
const initialState = {
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    isAuthenticated: null,
    loading: true,
    user: null,
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch (type) {
        case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
            localStorage.setItem('token', payload.token);
            return {
                ...state,
                ...payload,
                isAuthenticated: true,
                loading: false,
            };
        case LOGIN_FAIL:
            localStorage.removeItem('token');
            return {
                ...state,
                token: null,
                isAuthenticated: false,
                loading: false,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

**Login.js component**:

```
const Login = ({ loginUser, isAuthenticated }) => {
    const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
        email: '',
        password: '',
    });

    const { email, password } = formData;

    const onChange = (e) => {
        setFormData({ ...formData, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    const onSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        loginUser(email, password);
    };

    // Redirect if logged in
    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return <Navigate to='/dashboard' />;
    }

    return(some JSX form)

Login.propTypes = {
    login: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
};


const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
});

export default connect(null, { loginUser })(Login);
```

Edit: I found out that if I set connect() function first parameter to null, the component renders, but if I set the parameter to mapStateToProps it doesn't render (inside the component). Still, my issue is the same: isAuthenticated is undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you defining `rootReducer`?

My *guess*, without looking, is that you're either treating all of the `auth` reducer as `rootReducer`, *or* calling `combineReducers({authReducer})`.  In either case, there *won't* be a `state.auth` field, because your store configuration did not define one.

The short fix here is:

```js
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer
})
```

The better answer is to use [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-2-app-structure) and its `configureStore` API, instead of the legacy `createStore` API:

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer
  }
})
// this added `state.auth`, _and_ the thunk middleware, 
// _and_ the Redux DevTools, in one function call!
```

You should also be using RTK's `createSlice` instead of writing reducers by hand.

Comment: I've been following a course which uses .createStore(), however, when the course finishes I plan on implementing the Redux Toolkit package. This fixed my problem, thank you! :)